# VPython Install Issues

Tags: python, 64-bit, vpython

I'm trying to import the visual module for 64-bit python.  Unfortunately, I keep getting the following error:

> ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\python\color_space.py", line 2, in
>
> ```
>    from visual import scene, color, sphere
> ```
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\visual__init__.py", line 1, in
>
> ```
>    from .visual_all import *
> ```
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\visual\visual_all.py", line 1, in
>
> ```
>    from vis import version
> ```
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\vis__init__.py", line 3, in
>
> ```
>    from .cvisual import (vector, dot, mag, mag2, norm, cross, rotate,
> ```
>
> ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import

I've uninstalled my 64-bit version of python and tried the 32-bit version of python with a 32-bit visual module, to no success.  Now I've reverted to 64-bit.  Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you may not have numpy installed. You can download it here: http://www.scipy.org/Download/

Or it might not be in your python directory.

Comment: It's always the simple things, isn't it?  That was it.  Thanks for your help!